# Creating Network Between Macbooks for Screen Sharing

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have 1 Macbook Air and 1 Macbook Pro.

Macbook Pro screen is broken so I log into Macbook Pro by Screen Sharing app on my home local network and view it in my Macbook Air.

But for traveling, e.g. Hotel, how can I create a network between Macbook Air and Macbook Pro so that they can find their IPs and connect through Screen Sharing app?

Is it necessary to have router or modem to have those computers in network? Or is there any cable solution between computers that it can allow me to use Screen Sharing app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an ad-hoc (computer-to-computer) network which will allow the two computers to talk.

Click on the Wifi icon in your menubar.
Click `Create Network...`.
Put a Network Name (SSID) in the dialog box, choose a channel.
Click the `Create` button

On your other computer, join that network like any other Wi-Fi network.

You may be prohibited from creating an ad-hoc network. If so:

Go to `System Preferences -> Network -> Wi-Fi`. 
Click on the `Advanced` button, then the `Wi-Fi` menu item.
Deactivate the checkbox require admin to `Create computer-to-computer networks`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helped. Do you think is there a way to hide Wi-fi name? I do not want this wifi to be public visible. Also if I connect to this wifi by the 2nd computer, 2nd computer does not connect to internet. should not it gain the internet from the 1st computer's internet? This is not such a big problem but wanted to ask.

Comment: You can turn on internet sharing on the first computer. System Prefs->sharing

Comment: I don't think you can hide the SSID (Network Name), but I'm not sure